# C++: Is there a way to avoid redundancy with changing long declarations?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

This has always bugged me with C and C++:

In my header file I have something like:

```
bool UpdateWindow( int w, int h, char bpp, bool force, char* someOtherLongStuff )
```

Now, if I want to change that for whatever reason, I have to do so in both header and source file - that's annoying in my opinion.

Is there a way to automate this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: You may want to consider having less of `w`, `h` and `bpp` and more of `someOtherLongStuff`.

Comment: Although some tools may help you with that, it is a basic idiom of C and C++ to separate declarations from implementations for good reason. If you think thats annoying try java - ill stay with C++.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a shortcut for this, but even if one exists it might not give you as much of a saving as you imagine. If you are changing the header file then there are probably a lot of other places that will be affected by the change (the method body, other application code that includes this header, your client's code if you ship it as a library, unit tests, etc.) so having to change it in two places is just the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it running with [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) from Wholetomato. It's commercial but you could give it a try...

C++ was a long time ago - at least for me :)

Comment: Visual Assist definitely automates this. It also allows you to create a definition from the declaration (and vice versa I think) which is very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the standard visual studio. I think you need a refactoring tool like Resharper, but I am not sure it will work for C++. Refactoring for C++ is a very though problem.
My best shot would be to just follow the declaration with ctrl+click on the name and change in both sides.

Comment: ReSharper doesn't support C++.